# Need of JSON schema validator

Tags: java, regex, json, performance, rest

I get the REST request as an object. When comes to our application it automatically parses the  json string to an object. Then I need to validate it. I thought to validate with the json schema. There are not more than 20 properties on that object. But unknown parameters can be come to the request.

Is it a problem when consider the performance? what is the best way to do this? using the schema validator or doing it on the application code wise by using regex. Another thing is if I am using json schema validator I need to get the error messages and throw our own messages. for that I need to use the regex again.

Comment: *Do* you, or do you *not* have a predefined schema? You mention that unknown parameters are allowed -- in that case, why bother validating it at all? If it parses, it's valid. Unless you need it structured in a specific format, don't bother.

Comment: unknown parameters are ignored. but need to validate other properties. means lenght, pattern, mandatory fields, optional, multiple occurrence, etc.

Comment: You want it to programmatic/automatic? Can you use an external API or has to be local?

Comment: Either way, do NOT use regex to do it; use a proper validator. There are several: http://json-schema.org/implementations.html

Comment: (Sorry if that sounded harsh) just that regex isn't the right tool for it and you'll end up with a nightmare.

Comment: r3mus, there is no requirement to do it. I need the approach to implement it. this is a payment gateway. buyer passes the parameters, we need to validate it and send the errors back with our messages. if i use json-schema-validator i need to get the errors and check each and every error with regex and convert to our message and passes a list of error messages

Comment: Have a look at that url ^ there are a few in there, a couple for java particularly. Lets you specify a schema and handle the anomalies. I haven't personally used any for java, but it should get you started.